# Ramps 1.4 stepper motor Slaving

Tags: arduino, motor, driver, stepper-motor

So I am looking to run 2 stepper motors for x and y axis with a ramps 1.4 board, but since their are only one stepper motor driver per axis i was wondering how to accomplish this?
(I'm thinking a board to take the one stepper motor signal and duplicate for each axis, but this seams to me to be me over complicating it)

Comment: i answered the best I could, but are you sure it's not "XY" problem? Like, why would you need stepper motors for other axis? Maybe there is a simpler solution for your root problem, the one that prevented you from having just 1 motor?

Comment: Did you build a cnc with a really large x-axis?

Comment: well no but i want to run ball screws instead of the belt drive so i was thinking i would need 2 steppers(is this wrong) bed will bed 214mm*214mm

Comment: Is there sotmething like mechanical stack exchange? Ask there, but I don't think you need two. You can have one screw, under the middle of the bed. You will then just need two rods with sliders on the sides (just as you would with belt). The only reason you would need two on vertical axis is the fact that there is no way to get one in the middle there.

Comment: I think if i use 2 servo motors instead of steppers it would work better the only question is ho much weight can i put on the ballscrews since i want to attach my z axis to them and then off the z do my third axis

Answer (score 0):

See this image:

[image: Schema]

Source: http://forums.reprap.org/read.php?219,259333

Look on the right, below the middle. For Z, there are simply two sets of connectors, connected in parallel. If this is good to connect Z motors in parallel, it will be just as good to do the same with X and Y. All you need is simple Y cable, or one plug on both cables. Example of y cable:

[image: Example pic]